# PHP Namespace confusion - keyword v constant

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm learning about php namespaces just now and am stumped as to what the difference is between the namespace keyword and the namespace constant:

```
__NAMESPACE__
namespace
```

All the examples on php.net seem to use the keyword like so:

`namespace\MyClass` or something similar.  Which could easily have been done with the constant also.

Can someone explain the fundamental difference between them and when to use either over the other.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace keyword `namespace` is used to define a namespace in a file, similar to C#'s `namespace` keyword (but without the braces to define scope), or Java's `package` keyword.

In PHP, the `__NAMESPACE__` constant returns a string value of the current namespace scope name. Try to avoid using it as it muddies your code up, but it's useful when using strings as typenames.

There's more documentation in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php

Comment: the `namespace` keyword is used only to declare a namespace, to use a namespace you have to use the `use` keyword.